# HapiJS serving file

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I want to serving file (with NodeJS and HapiJS) without saving to file system.

I have two server.
I need to serve static content from server2 to client passing through server1.
So when client go to my route, I make a call in server1 to server2 for saving file in server1 and reply with it

I make a request to a server like this:

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://192.168.11.101:8080' + req_path,
    headers: {
        Cookie: jCookie
    }
};
var full_name = '/tmp/test.' + format;

var stream = httpRequest(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(full_name));
```

At this moment file was saved and I can reply with it.

I want to reply directly without saving to my file system, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean without saving to filesystem? Where is the file coming from? Who are you sending it to? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Now it's more clear @MattHarrison

Comment: So you want to use it as a proxy?

Comment: roughly... I want to reply file of server2 without saving on server1. I don't think is it possibile with HapiJS and NodeJS :) @Clarkie

Comment: So you're building a proxy. Have a look at h2o2 (https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) if you're using hapi

Comment: It definitely is possible with hapi and node. There's no need to touch filesystem to proxy a file, you just buffer whatever you get from the upstream server into memory until the downstream client can read it.

Comment: Ok thank, I think with h2o2 that you linked me is possible :), but take a look, I need to pass Cookie... @MattHarrison

Comment: You can choose pass any headers you want (or not) in either direction.

Comment: Sorry but I don't find how pass cookie, because require basic http authentication, proxy work but browser show me http authentication @MattHarrison

Comment: Maybe post another question on here showing your implementation so far with h2o2 and a specific question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to send as a stream rather than saving the file.Hope this helpful to you.

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream(httpRequest(options));
      stream.on('data', function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('loaded part of the file');
        //reply(null,data);
        reply(data).header('Content-Type', 'file content type').header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=ex.txt');
      });
      stream.on('end', function()
      {
        console.log('file send sucessfully');
      });
```